# What is the purpose of this code in IdentityHashMap.hash()?

Tags: java, hash, java-8, hashmap, bit-shift

```java
/**
 * Returns index for Object x.
 */
private static int hash(Object x, int length) {
    int h = System.identityHashCode(x);
    // Multiply by -127, and left-shift to use least bit as part of hash
    return ((h << 1) - (h << 8)) & (length - 1);
}
```

From: [jdk/IdentityHashMap.java at jdk8-b120 · openjdk/jdk · GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk8-b120/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/IdentityHashMap.java#L308)

In theory, the hash values returned by `System.identityHashCode()` are already uniformly distributed, so why is there an additional shift operation instead of a direct AND operation with `length - 1`?

The implementation seems to guarantee that the lowest bit is 0 to ensure that the result of the calculation is an even number, because the implementation requires all keys to be on even indices and all values to be on odd indices.

`h << 8` seems to mix the low and high bits to handle the scenario when System.identityHashCode() is implemented as a memory address or an incrementing value, it is not clear why only 8 bits are shifted here instead of something like `HashMap.hash()` moves 16 bits as well.

Comment: That code neccessary leaves the lowest bit at 0, which seems to be obliterating hash uniqueness. Presumably the impl needs that bit for other purposes. `System.identityHashCode` does not _guarantee_ that its values are uniformly distributed. Not that this formula does a particularly good job at smearing out clustered hashes. Quite the mystery!

Comment: Now I know the reason to shift left by one bit, because the implementation requires the key to be at the even index and the value to be at the odd index, just don't know why `h << 8` is subtracted.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that ```Multiply by -127``` should be ```Multiply by -254```.  This was an wrong comment and has been [fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046362).

Comment: @Poison `x<<8 - x<<1` is  the same as `* -254`. Just - faster on most architectures. _Why_ * -254? - see the answers.

Comment: @rwitserloot `x<<1 - x<<8`, that is.

Comment: @zysaaa Just a little ambiguity, because multiplying by -127 and then doing a left-shift is equivalent to multiplying by -254. Of course the explanation in JDK 15 is more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch of what’s going on here is that it’s designed to address two issues.

First, the slot index this function produces must be an even number. (The implementation stores keys at even table slots and values at odd table slots.) This means that whatever index is returned must have its last bit equal to zero.

Second, the identity hash codes used are (potentially) based on memory addresses, and low bits of memory addresses are “more random” than high bits. For example, if we allocate a list of objects and the allocator places them all consecutively in memory, their addresses will all have the same high bits but different low bits. (Or perhaps there’s just a global counter of objects that’s incremented when an object is created. In that case, the low bits of object hashes will similarly have a wider dispersion than the high bits.)

To make sure things are spread out in the table, we’d therefore like to “mix” the low bits of the hash code with the “high” bits of the hash code. The effect of subtracting out `h << 8` is to shift the low bits of the identity hash code higher up, flip them, and add them back to the hash code, causing a bunch of “ripples” as the addition plays out. I think (?) this is an effective way to then inject higher entropy low bits into the high bits, giving a more uniform hash over the array of slots once the table starts getting larger and larger.

Comment: Mixing low bits into high bits seems like a more appropriate explanation, but why `h << 8` instead of `h << 16`? The implementation in HashMap.hash() shifts 16 bits when mixing high and low bits.

Comment: That’s a very good question that I don’t have an answer for. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The comments in the code say:

> *"Implementation note: This is a simple *linear-probe* hash table, as described for example in texts by Sedgewick and Knuth.  The array alternates holding keys and values."*

In fact the the `hash` method returns a value that is used as a direct index into the array.  For example:

```
public V get(Object key) {
    Object k = maskNull(key);
    Object[] tab = table;
    int len = tab.length;
    int i = hash(k, len);
    while (true) {
        Object item = tab[i];
        if (item == k)
            return (V) tab[i + 1];
        if (item == null)
            return null;
        i = nextKeyIndex(i, len);
    }
}
```

That means that `hash` needs to return an even value.  The calculation in `hash` is ensuring that the index is even without throwing away the bottom bit of the `System.identityHashCode(x)` value.

Why not just throw away the bottom bit?

Well, the answer is in the way that `System.identityHashCode` is implemented.  In reality, there are multiple algorithms for generating the hash, and the algorithm used (at runtime) depends on an obscure JVM command line option.

- Some algorithms are (notionally) evenly distributed across the range of `int`.  For those, discarding the bottom bit would be fine.
- Other algorithm are not like this.  One of algorithm uses a simple global counter.  Another uses the object's memory address with the bottom 3 bits removed.  If these algorithms are selected, discarding the LSB would increase the probability of hash collisions in `IdentityHashMap`.

See https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/26-identity-hash-code/ for more information on `IdentityHashcode` algorithms and how they are selected.  Note that this aspect of JVM behavior is unspecified and liable to be version specific.

Comment: I think this is less about “don’t throw away the bottom bit” and more about “mix the low bits with the high bits.” But perhaps I’m mistaken?

Comment: They are saying the same thing.  If you don't mix the bottom bit you are discarding it.  If you don't discard it you have to mix it in.

Comment: Good point! Though I’m wondering if it’s beyond just preserving that low bit in some way and instead is more about spreading the entropy around.

Comment: Well ... again ... it is the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify - the mixing operation here mixes the low byte of the hash code with the high bytes. You could imagine another mixing operator that just takes the discarded bit and mixes it with the remaining bits. This one seems to specifically prioritize mixing all eight low bits with the upper bits.

Comment: OK ... I don't understand the maths ... and my brain is a bit too old ... but in the cases where the numbers are not uniform, it looks like the bottom bit *should* have priority over (say) the top bit, because the top bit is highly predictable; see the heatmap graphics in the Shiplev article.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why `h << 8` is subtracted, according to my understanding,  `h << 1` doesn't throw away the LSB, it just moves the LSB to the second bit, which is really thrown away is the MSB. `h << 1` guarantees that the LSB is 0, that is, the result of the final calculation must be an even number.

Comment: A simple `h << 1` throws away the MSB. Depending on the distribution of inputs (e.g. if the LSB is constant and the MSB isn't) doing that can discard more entropy than you need to.  The point is that this transformation is a *heuristic* that is (presumably) designed to "work well" with all of practical algorithm choices.  Presumably they did a bunch of testing, and transformation provides a good compromise between preserving entropy and cost of the transformation.  But you would really need to ask the engineers how they actually decided.